# Gradle Console missing from Intellij Idea

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I just started using IntelliJ Idea v15 and after spending a long time in Android Studio I'm feeling a bit lost. Where is the Gradle console window from Android Studio? Is it not implemented? Is there a plugin that adds it?

Here's a screenshot of my IntelliJ15 windows after running a build:
[image]

Comment: If it exists, you could probably find it with the search all feature (press shift twice and search Gradle Console).

Comment: Press shift twice? Oh and didn't know that one! I searched and it's not there either.

Comment: You probably need to enable Gradle for the project then. I mostly use maven, and what I do in my cases is I just 'Import an existing project', select the root pom.xml, and then the project is configured as a maven project automatically by IntelliJ. So I suspect the same would work for Gradle as well. I just looked at [IntelliJ's docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gradle-tool-window.html) and it looks like you need to do exactly that - import the project by the build.gradle file. Also, double shift will become your best friend :)

Comment: Gradle is automatically enabled for my Android project. You're probably misunderstanding. I have all of the Gradle tool windows I just don't have the special Gradle console window from Android Studio that logs all of the gradle build activity.

Comment: If you are using Intellij 2016, they have hidden it it:
[Where do the server's and the app's messages display in Intellij 2016?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094228/where-do-the-servers-and-the-apps-messages-display-in-intellij-2016)

Comment: I am using IDEA 2016.3 with android plugin and have same issue. There is no console tab and any buttons as @Sander says after application build.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Just close the project and import it again as a gradle project.

`Open ...` -> choose the build.gradle file of your project.

Comment: Make sure you purge the .idea and .gradle directories in your project root directory.

Answer (score 4):

I also could not make this work - even after reimporting the project (in IntelliJ 2017.1 community edition).
However, as a workaround you can switch to text mode:

**task mode:**

[image]

**text mode:**

[image]