# Where do the server's and the app's messages display in Intellij 2016?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle, console

When running a Gradle project in IntelliJ 15, I would get verbose output like this, spoonfeeding me with a link to click to launch my app, and see output statements using a `println` statement as described below.
[image]

Now, I just installed IntelliJ 2016 and here is  what the Run output window looks like; and that's it! No link, and I can't see the output of my `println` statements like before! Just useless spinners counting time and nothing else. Am I missing a window or something?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The console output view is still there; you're just seeing the new Gradle Task view, which is now the default. Just click the little icon on the top left of the Run window to toggle between the Tasks view and the plain console view.

[image: Click here to toggle from the new Gradle Task view]

Once you switch, you'll get the exact same console view you're used to:

[image: Click here to return to the Task view]